# How to add dojo to websphere portal 7 custom theme?

Tags: dojo, lotus, websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm

I create a custom theme in WebSphere portal 7.But dojo is not configured .
Is there any way to add all dojo js to custom theme.

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: What type of theme are you creating? One that's based on PageBuilder2 or the Modular theme? Also, what is going on that indicates dojo is not configured? Typically these themes come with dojo already set to go.

Comment: I created a custom theme using default theme Portal 7.0.0.2. I created a Carousel component on added this to portlet. On browser viewed tat page and in firebug console showing that dojo is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The 7.0.0.2 theme uses the deferred profile by default. This profile only loads dojo when it's needed. You can either

- [Set the theme to use the full profile](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Changing_the_theme_default_profile_wp8&content=pdcontent)

or

- [Create your own profile that includes dojo on page load](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Specifying_profile_files_wp8&content=pdcontent) and set the theme to use that.